# 同一ブラウザ複数タブでも挙動不正とならない設計

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring bootにて同一ブラウザ複数タブで運用可能な画面設計としたいです。

ブラウザ内でセッション情報はタブ内で共有される為、動作不良とユーザより指摘受けています。

タブ毎でセッション情報を扱うようにしたいのですが、spring bootで可能なのかどうか、ご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: (タブを開くたびに認証操作からやり直したい、ということでもない限り要件定義に問題がありそうに思われます)ともあれ、どのタブからリクエストされてきたのかはサーバーサイドでは知り得ないので、Spring Bootというよりはフロント(JS)の話がメインになるかと考えます。Spring Boot でJWT認証を行うサンプルなどを検索してみると、Web Storageに認証情報を格納する実装などが見つかるかと思いますのでそれらが参考になるのではないでしょうか([sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)はタブ間でデータ共有されません; 例えば[こちら](https://volkruss.com/posts/p3448/)はlocalStorage を利用していますが、これを sessionStorage に変更するイメージです)